# Collect all parameters from all reports in reportserver folder and populate a sql table

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, reporting, checklistbox

[Thanks to Filburt and Devjosh. I have restructured the post and included my attempt approach. ]
I have a table on my SQL DB call ReportList which is a list of report. I need to go through that list and interrogate the reportserver, eport by report, to populate a table called ReportParameters. The ReportParameters table has a column for ReportOwnerID which needs to contains the ReportID value of the corresponding (owner) report as listed in the ReportList table.

This is in VB.NET 2005 ASP2.0 and I have ended up with a mess. Please help me with the cleanest approach to doing this.

It needs to work so:-  I have a listbox of the reports as per REportList and a GridView that list all the parameters (uniquely - most of the parameters are common to many reports) the idea being that the parameters get set once and the report can be kicked off by selecting them in the ReportList CheckListBox and clicking on Execute.

I would like it that as I click on a particular report in the ListView, the relevant parameters in the Gridview get a green background and those that do not apply are red. The leftmost column in the gridview contains tha Parameter NAME (not editable) and the next column must be editable to populate the value.

DONE SO FAR:

I have tried on clicking the EXECUTE button , to build a parameters string in a testbox and call that with the Javascript OpenReportWin() function when I open the report in a new window. This works fine, but my biggest issue it interrogating the reportserver reports to get back a list of parameters and dooping them into a table. I have triend to use a hidden DataGrid bound to a ds onto the reportParamaters table; I have tried to poulate it using a datalist but I cannot get the hang of these thionsg and its looking messy. Ther must be a simple clean way of gettting the .GetParameters resultset back from the report server and populating the table without having to create a reportviewer object and cycling through the list of reports - it then has to render each report before you can get that list out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will withdraw this for now. I will submit a solution when I am comfortable that I have reahced a clean solution.

Mac

PLEASE CLOSE!!!